# Difference between Divide and Conquer Algo and Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

What is the difference between Divide and Conquer Algorithms and Dynamic Programming Algorithms? How are the two terms different? I do not understand the difference between them.

Please take a simple example to explain any difference between the two and on what ground they seem to be similar.

Answer (score 217):

**Divide and Conquer**

Divide and Conquer works by dividing the problem into sub-problems, conquer each sub-problem recursively and combine these solutions.

**Dynamic Programming**

Dynamic Programming is a technique for solving problems with overlapping subproblems. Each sub-problem is solved only once and the result of each sub-problem is stored in a table ( generally implemented as an array or a hash table) for future references. These sub-solutions may be used to obtain the original solution and the technique of storing the sub-problem solutions is known as memoization.

You may think of `DP = recursion + re-use`

A classic example to understand the difference would be to see both these approaches towards obtaining the nth fibonacci number. Check this [material](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring08/notes/lecture19.pdf) from MIT.

---

**Divide and Conquer approach**
[image: Divide and Conquer approach]

**Dynamic Programming Approach**
[image]

Comment: how did you make the images? using mouse ?

Comment: I think the most important line in this whole answer is that: "overlapping subproblems". DP has it, Divide and Conquer doesn't

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik Overlapping sub problem means a problem that occurs over and over again. Like solving fn-2 in  the example shown above. So in D&C it is there and this why it is not as efficient as DP.

Comment: Strange! 'Overlapping subproblems' you're talking about the problem but 'dynamic programming' is a kind of algorithm. I think it's important to distinguish 'problems' and 'algorithms'.

Comment: Yes, DP memoizes the overlapping portions to gain an advantage over Divide and Conquer.

Comment: I would say that Divide and Conquer **could** be used to solve overlapping sub problems but in that case the solution for those problems is not stored (memoized).

Comment: I agree, divide and conquer *can* have overlapping subproblems, it's just more efficient if you memoize it so that you don't end up doing repeated work. So, DP should be thought of as an extension to divide and conquer, like the answer below describes really well! When you are given a problem, work out the D&C solution first, then apply DP.

Comment: @VihaanVerma Not an op, but probably that image was created with an iPad and an Apple pencil. Hard to write all that clean using a mouse.

Answer (score 76):

### Dynamic Programming and Divide-and-Conquer Similarities

As I see it for now I can say that **dynamic programming is an extension of divide and conquer paradigm**.

I would not treat them as something completely different. Because **they both work by recursively breaking down a problem into two or more sub-problems** of the same or related type, until these become simple enough to be solved directly. The solutions to the sub-problems are then combined to give a solution to the original problem.

So why do we still have different paradigm names then and why I called dynamic programming an extension. It is because dynamic programming approach may be applied to the problem **only if the problem has certain restrictions or prerequisites**. And after that dynamic programming extends divide and conquer approach with **memoization** or **tabulation** technique.

Let’s go step by step…

### Dynamic Programming Prerequisites/Restrictions

As we’ve just discovered there are two key attributes that divide and conquer problem must have in order for dynamic programming to be applicable:

- **Optimal substructure** — optimal solution can be constructed from optimal solutions of its subproblems
- **Overlapping sub-problems** — problem can be broken down into subproblems which are reused several times or a recursive algorithm for the problem solves the same subproblem over and over rather than always generating new subproblems

Once these two conditions are met we can say that this divide and conquer problem may be solved using dynamic programming approach.

### Dynamic Programming Extension for Divide and Conquer

Dynamic programming approach extends divide and conquer approach with two techniques (**memoization** and **tabulation**) that both have a purpose of storing and re-using sub-problems solutions that may drastically improve performance. For example naive recursive implementation of Fibonacci function has time complexity of `O(2^n)` where DP solution doing the same with only `O(n)` time.

**Memoization (top-down cache filling)** refers to the technique of caching and reusing previously computed results. The memoized `fib` function would thus look like this:

```
memFib(n) {
    if (mem[n] is undefined)
        if (n < 2) result = n
        else result = memFib(n-2) + memFib(n-1)
        
        mem[n] = result
    return mem[n]
}
```

**Tabulation (bottom-up cache filling)** is similar but focuses on filling the entries of the cache. Computing the values in the cache is easiest done iteratively. The tabulation version of `fib` would look like this:

```
tabFib(n) {
    mem[0] = 0
    mem[1] = 1
    for i = 2...n
        mem[i] = mem[i-2] + mem[i-1]
    return mem[n]
}
```

You may read more about memoization and tabulation comparison [here](https://programming.guide/dynamic-programming-vs-memoization-vs-tabulation.html).

The main idea you should grasp here is that because our divide and conquer problem has overlapping sub-problems the caching of sub-problem solutions becomes possible and thus memoization/tabulation step up onto the scene.

### So What the Difference Between DP and DC After All

Since we’re now familiar with DP prerequisites and its methodologies we’re ready to put all that was mentioned above into one picture.

[image: Dynamic Programming vs Divide-and-Conquer]

If you want to see code examples you may take a look at [more detailed explanation here](https://trekhleb.dev/blog/2018/dynamic-programming-vs-divide-and-conquer/) where you'll find two algorithm examples: Binary Search and Minimum Edit Distance (Levenshtein Distance) that are illustrating the difference between DP and DC.

Comment: Offtopic: Did you use a graphics tablet to draw that?

Comment: @GeonGeorge no, the drawing was made by pen and then scanned

Comment: this is one of the best answers I've read about organizing DP

Comment: this is how dynamic programming should be taught!

Comment: I also think like you, but my friends don't see like it, that's why I come here to see if I can find someone with similar view to me. One question, could you please explain a bit more when do we have "Optimal substructure" and when not?

Answer (score 32):

The other difference between divide and conquer and dynamic programming could be:

Divide and conquer:

1. Does more work on the sub-problems and hence has more time consumption.
2. In divide and conquer the sub-problems are independent of each other.

Dynamic programming:

1. Solves the sub-problems only once and then stores it in the table.
2. In dynamic programming the sub-problem are not independent.

Comment: Divide-and-conquer algorithms don't necessarily do more work than their DP alternatives. One example is Erickson's algorithm for finding maximal arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 19):

sometimes when programming recursivly, you call the function with the same parameters multiple times which is unnecassary.

The famous example Fibonacci numbers:

```
           index: 1,2,3,4,5,6...
Fibonacci number: 1,1,2,3,5,8...

function F(n) {
    if (n < 3)
        return 1
    else
        return F(n-1) + F(n-2)
}
```

Let's run F(5):

```
F(5) = F(4) + F(3)
     = {F(3)+F(2)} + {F(2)+F(1)}
     = {[F(2)+F(1)]+1} + {1+1}
     = 1+1+1+1+1
```

So we have called :
1 times F(4)
2 times F(3)
3 times F(2)
2 times F(1)

Dynamic Programming approach: if you call a function with the same parameter more than once, save the result into a variable to directly access it on next time. The iterative way:

```
if (n==1 || n==2)
    return 1
else
    f1=1, f2=1
    for i=3 to n
         f = f1 + f2
         f1 = f2
         f2 = f
```

Let's call F(5) again:

```
fibo1 = 1
fibo2 = 1 
fibo3 = (fibo1 + fibo2) = 1 + 1 = 2
fibo4 = (fibo2 + fibo3) = 1 + 2 = 3
fibo5 = (fibo3 + fibo4) = 2 + 3 = 5
```

As you can see, whenever you need the multiple call you just access the corresponding variable to get the value instead of recalculating it.

By the way, dynamic programming doesn't mean to convert a recursive code into an iterative code. You can also save the subresults into a variable if you want a recursive code. In this case the technique is called memoization. For our example it looks like this:

```
// declare and initialize a dictionary
var dict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
for i=1 to n
    dict[i] = -1

function F(n) {
    if (n < 3)
        return 1
    else
    {
        if (dict[n] == -1)
            dict[n] = F(n-1) + F(n-2)

        return dict[n]                
    }
}
```

So the relationship to the Divide and Conquer is that D&D algorithms rely on recursion. And some versions of them has this "multiple function call with the same parameter issue." Search for "matrix chain multiplication" and "longest common subsequence" for such examples where DP is needed to improve the T(n) of D&D algo.

Answer (score 12):

I assume you have already read Wikipedia and other academic resources on this, so I won't recycle any of that information. I must also caveat that I am not a computer science expert by any means, but I'll share my two cents on my understanding of these topics...

### Dynamic Programming

Breaks the problem down into discrete subproblems. The recursive algorithm for the Fibonacci sequence is an example of Dynamic Programming, because it solves for fib(n) by first solving for fib(n-1). In order to solve the original problem, it solves a *different* problem.

### Divide and Conquer

These algorithms typically solve similar pieces of the problem, and then put them together at the end. Mergesort is a classic example of divide and conquer. The main difference between this example and the Fibonacci example is that in a mergesort, the division can (theoretically) be arbitrary, and no matter how you slice it up, you are still merging and sorting. The same amount of *work* has to be done to mergesort the array, no matter how you divide it up. Solving for fib(52) requires *more steps* than solving for fib(2).

Answer (score 9):

I think of `Divide & Conquer` as an recursive approach and `Dynamic Programming` as table filling.

For example, `Merge Sort` is a `Divide & Conquer` algorithm, as in each step, you split the array into two halves, recursively call `Merge Sort` upon the two halves and then merge them.

`Knapsack` is a `Dynamic Programming` algorithm as you are filling a table representing optimal solutions to subproblems of the overall knapsack. Each entry in the table corresponds to the maximum value you can carry in a bag of weight w given items 1-j.

Comment: While this is true for a lot of cases, it is not always true that we store the results of the subproblems in a table.

Answer (score 5):

**Divide and Conquer** involves three steps at each level of recursion:

1. **Divide** the problem into subproblems.
2. **Conquer** the subproblems by solving them recursively.
3. **Combine** the solution for subproblems into the solution for original problem.

   - It is a **top-down** approach.
   - It does more work on subproblems and hence has more time
     consumption.
   - eg. n-th term of Fibonacci series can be computed in O(2^n) time complexity.

**Dynamic Programming** involves the following four steps: 
 
  1. **Characterise** the structure of optimal solutions.

  2. **Recursively define** the values of optimal solutions.

 3. **Compute** the value of optimal solutions.

 4. **Construct** an Optimal Solution **from computed information**.

- It is a **Bottom-up** approach.
- Less time consumption than divide and conquer since we make use of the values computed earlier, rather than computing again.
- eg. n-th term of Fibonacci series can be computed in O(n) time complexity.

***For easier understanding, lets see divide and conquer as a brute force solution and its optimisation as dynamic programming.***

 
**N.B.** divide and conquer algorithms with overlapping subproblems can only be optimised with dp.

Comment: Divide and Conquer is Bottom-up and 
Dynamic Programming is  top-down

Answer (score 3):

- **Divide and Conquer**

  - They broke into non-overlapping sub-problems
  - Example: factorial numbers i.e. fact(n) = n*fact(n-1)

```
fact(5) = 5* fact(4) = 5 * (4 * fact(3))= 5 * 4 * (3 *fact(2))= 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * (fact(1))
```

As we can see above, no fact(x) is repeated so factorial has non overlapping problems.

- **Dynamic Programming**

  - They Broke into overlapping sub-problems
  - Example: Fibonacci numbers i.e. fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

```
fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3) = (fib(3)+fib(2)) + (fib(2)+fib(1))
```

As we can see above, fib(4) and fib(3) both use fib(2). similarly so many fib(x) gets repeated. that's why Fibonacci has overlapping sub-problems.

- As a result of the repetition of sub-problem in DP, we can keep such results in a table and save computation effort. this is called as **memoization**

Answer (score 1):

**Divide and Conquer**

- In this problem is solved in following three steps:
  **1. Divide** - Dividing into number of sub-problems
  **2. Conquer** - Conquering by solving sub-problems recursively
  **3. Combine** - Combining sub-problem solutions to get original problem's solution
- Recursive approach
- Top Down technique
- **Example:** Merge Sort

**Dynamic Programming**

- In this the problem is solved in following steps:
  **1.** Defining structure of optimal solution
  **2.** Defines value of optimal solutions repeatedly.
  **3.** Obtaining values of optimal solution in bottom-up fashion
  **4.** Getting final optimal solution from obtained values
- Non-Recursive
- Bottom Up Technique
- **Example:** Strassen's Matrix Multiplication

Comment: your answer is the answer of @Neel Alex, below. !!!!

Comment: I didn't check that before answering may be I missed that at that time. But same question can have same answer because there are different sources of learning free of cost available online.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and Conquer:

This paradigm involves three stages:

1. Divide the problem into smaller sub-problems
2. Conquer, i.e., solve these smaller sub-problems
3. Combine these sub-problems' solutions to get the final answer.

Dynamic Programming:

DP is an optimization of recursive solutions. The primary difference it makes is that it stores the solution to sub-problems, which can later be accessed during the process of finding solutions of the remaining sub-problems. This is done so that we don't have to calculate the solution to a sub-problem every time, rather we can simply look it up the computer memory to retrieve its value, given that it has been solved earlier. We can simply add this as our base case in recursion. For example, we are solving a problem through recursion, we can store the solutions to sub-problems in an array and access them by adding the relevant code in one of our base cases in the recursive method.

There are two ways in which DP is done:

Consider a problem: To find factorial of x.

1. Tabulation: We use the bottom up approach, that is we go from the smallest numbers all the way upto x, to find the solution.

Pseudo Code:

```
 1. int array
 2. for int=1, i<=x, i++
 3. array[i] = array[i-1]*i
```

2. Memoization: We use the top down approach, that is we take the problem and then break it down into smaller parts and solve them, to get the final solution

Pseudo Code:

```
 fac():
 1. int array
 2. if(x==0): return 1
 3. if(array[x]!=null): return array[x]
 4. return array[x] = x*fac(x-1)
```